# How to download Mysql jdbc jar file on centos

Tags: mysql, linux, jdbc, centos

Sorry for my noobness. I'm very newbie in linux and using CentOS. I need to download Mysql jdbc and place it in somewhere. So I searched on Google and couldn't get any proper result. All results say that download it from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html site or download rpm and install it. But I really don't know how to download it first.

Comment: Sorry guys for my unclearness. Actually I'm connecting to server on which centos is installed through putty program. So what you're saying is exactly I wanna know that how to download it from console of putty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I just need to write this on the console

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.tar.gz. -O /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz
```

Then it downloads mysql-connector.tar.gz file in /tmp directory and to extract it I used this command:

```
tar -xvzf mysql-connector.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 14):

**Debian based distros (e.g. ubuntu):**

```
apt-get install libmysql-java
```

**Redhat based distros (e.g. centos):**

```
yum install mysql-connector-java
```

These packages will install the latest MySQL JDBC connector jar which takes some of the headache out of downloading and ensuring the jar is in the correct folder in the classpath for your app.  You may still need to move the jar to a specific folder in your classpath but I've found that it just works for hive and some other hadoopy things.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Connector/J from here
   http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.tar.gz
2. extract it and use it

Comment: Sorry guys for my unclearness. Actually I'm connecting to server on which centos is installed through putty program. So what you're saying is exactly I wanna know that how to download it from console of putty

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Mysql JDBC connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) and choose platform independent, click download on option having tar.gz format it will be downloaded and extract it to your current local drive.

Comment: Sorry guys for my unclearness. Actually I'm connecting to server on which centos is installed through putty program. So what you're saying is exactly I wanna know that how to download it from console of putty

Comment: you can use simply wget or first download all the dependencies to your local UI based system and finally, make use of any file transfer protocol to send those to your remote system.